# pass certain value dynamically to computed function in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-8, vuejs3

Im trying to pass an **id** with the **v-model** so i can pass that to my computed function. The purpose of my function is to dynamically filter a table without hardcoding the names in the function. The function has to be able to filter both select boxes.

my data is called **guides**, it has an **title/active/language_id/group**.

this is my html dropdown:

```html
    <select v-model="filterResult" :id="language.id" class="select2-selection custom-select">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option v-for="language in languages" v-bind:key="language.id" v-bind:value="language.id">{{ language.name }}</option>
    </select>

    <select v-model="filterResult" :id="active" class="select2-selection custom-select">
       <option value="">All</option>
       <option :value=1>Active</option>
       <option :value=2>Archived</option>
    </select>
```

Here is my computed function now, but as u can see the **"language.id"** is hard coded in but i want the function to read it out of **`<select>`**. what i tried is putting it in the **:id=""** but i have no idea to forward it to the function besides the **v-model.** Purpose of all this is so i can reuse the component without changing anything. So it has to be applied to both select boxes or even more in the future.

```
    filterCertainValue: function (evt) {
        if (!this.filterResult) return this.guides;
        return this.guides.filter(guide => {
            if (guide.language.id == this.filterResult) {
                return guide.language.id;
            }
        })
    },
```

Comment: I dont have any errors or problems. The thing is that im inexperienced and have no clue how to get what i want. As ur demo shows u got one selectbox right now for languages, let's say that i got another selectbox below that one for "active" instead "language_id". What i want is that i can use the vue function to apply to both of them, but thats not possible right now because as u can see the function is saying return language.id. but i want the return to change upon what selectbox has been touched.

Comment: @tony19 https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-computed-prop-forked-o0fov?file=/src/components/Guides.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dynamic filter key that changes based on the last selected `<select>`:

1. Create a [data property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) (named `"filterKey"`):

   ```js
   export default {
     data() {
       return {
         filterKey: null
       }
     }
   }
   ```
2. Add a [`change`-event handler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) to each `<select>` to set `filterKey` to the desired key to use in the computed prop's filtering (e.g., `language_id` or `active`):

   ```html
   <select @change="filterKey = 'language_id'">
     <!-- language_id options -->
   </select>

   <select @change="filterKey = 'active'">
     <!-- active options -->
   </select>
   ```
3. Update the computed prop's filter to use the `filterKey`:

   ```js
   computed: {
     filterCertainValue() {
       if (!this.filterResult) return this.guides
                                                   
       return this.guides.filter(guide => guide[this.filterKey] === this.filterResult)
     }
   },
   ```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/troubleshooting-computed-prop-vdrgb?file=/src/components/Guides.vue)